# Parsing unclosed `<br>` tags with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup has logic for closing consecutive `<br>` tags that doesn't do quite what I want it to do. For example,

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> bs = BeautifulSoup('one<br>two<br>three<br>four')
```

The HTML would render as

```
one
two
three
four
```

I'd like to parse it into a list of strings, `['one','two','three','four']`. BeautifulSoup's tag-closing logic means that I get nested tags when I ask for all the `<br>` elements.

```
>>> bs('br')
[<br>two<br>three<br>four</br></br></br>,
 <br>three<br>four</br></br>,
 <br>four</br>]
```

Is there a simple way to get the result I want?

Comment: Is there a way to surmount this behaviour of <br>? It's ruining the sibling structure.

Answer (score 11):

```
import bs4 as bs
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup('one<br>two<br>three<br>four')
print(soup.find_all(text=True))
```

yields

```
[u'one', u'two', u'three', u'four']
```

---

Or, using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/):

```
import lxml.html as LH
doc = LH.fromstring('one<br>two<br>three<br>four')
print(list(doc.itertext()))
```

yields

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

Comment: Did not know about this functionality.  Great answer.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using `bs4`, but this doesn't work. It picks the first item (`one`) but not the others.