# Extracting text between <br> with beautifulsoup, but without next tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm using python + beautifulsoup to try to get the text between the br's. The closest I got to this was by using next_sibling in the following manner:

```
<html>
<body>
</a><span class="strong">Title1</span>
<p>Text1</p>
<br>The Text I want to get<br>
<p>Text I dont want</p>
</body>
</html>

for span in soup.findAll("span", {"class" : "strong"}):
    print(span.next_sibling.next_sibling.text)
```

But this prints:

```
The Text I want to getText I dont want
```

So what i want is after the first p, but before the second, but I can't figure out how to extract when there are no real tags, and only just the br's as references.

I need it to print:

```
The Text I want to get
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the *HTML you've provided is broken*, the behavior would differ from [parser to parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) that `BeautifulSoup` uses.

In case of [`lxml` parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser), `BeautifulSoup` would convert the `br` tag into a self-closing one:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
>>> print soup
<html>
<body>
<span class="strong">Title1</span>
<p>Text1</p>
<br/>The Text I want to get<br/>
<p>Text I dont want</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that you would need [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) to be installed. If it is okay for you - find the `br` and get the next sibling:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """your HTML"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print(soup.br.next_sibling)  # prints "The Text I want to get"
```

Also see:

- [Using beautifulsoup to extract text between line breaks (e.g. <br /> tags)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275359/using-beautifulsoup-to-extract-text-between-line-breaks-e-g-br-tags)
- [Parsing unclosed `<br>` tags with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481408/parsing-unclosed-br-tags-with-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0):

Using Python Scrapy

```
In [4]: hxs.select('//body/text()').extract()
Out[4]: [u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'The Text I want to get', u'\n', u'\n']
```